# restart linux web server using ssh

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have shut down my linux web server using ssh command

```
  ~# shutdown -h now
```

how can i restart the server again. i am trying out different things but they are not helping. How to restart using ssh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have powered off the machine, you can't restart it from SSH. unless it supports Wake from Lan.

If you want to only restart your web server use

`apachectl restart`

Answer (score 25):

`reboot`

or if you want to restart just apache then

`/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

and if you want to shutdown then instead of `shutdown -h now` you can simply use `poweroff`

Comment: How do you know it's Apache and not Nginx or something else?

Answer (score 4):

You have shut down your server. Unless server supports `wake from lan` option, you can no longer turn it on remotely.

To restart server, use `reboot` command through ssh.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't advise how to remotely turn on the server. But if you are asking how to reboot it next time, use
"shutdown -r now"

Answer (score 0):

It depends what kind of server it is and what remote access facilities you have. If you did not personally (or your colleagues) set up the server, you should contact whoever did and ask them how to do this.

It is possible they may charge for this "remote hands" service if they have to physically access it (NB: rebooting is often handled by a separate system; many dedicated providers have their own systems for PDU remote control etc. A virtualised server probably does not need a remote hands request to reboot, because it can be handled by the hypervisor's control interface to which you may have some access).